# Self-signed SSL certificate (added to Keychain and marked Trusted) is displayed Invalid in Chrome

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, certificate, keychain

I've created `Root CA`, `Root PEM`.
Then I've created `mysite.key` and `mysite.crt` for my website running on `mysite.localhost`
Root PEM is added to Keychain and is marked as `Always trust`

When I visit my website on the left of the address bar I see `Not Secure` note.
When I click on it, it is read that the Certificate is Invalid.

However, when I go further in the popup I see a chain where my Root CA cert **IS trusted**, My website cert **IS valid**. When I expand a "trust" section for the website and set it to "always trust" those changes are not saved.

What am I doing wrong? I'd like to get rid of this notice since I've marked my certificate as trusted.

[image]

[image]

[image]

**UPDATE**
I've checked the certificates with `openssl s_client`

```
openssl s_client -connect raceplace.localhost:443

...
depth=0 C = CA, ST = None, L = NB, O = None, CN = raceplace.localhost
verify error:num=20:unable to get local issuer certificate
verify return:1
depth=0 C = CA, ST = None, L = NB, O = None, CN = raceplace.localhost
verify error:num=21:unable to verify the first certificate
verify return:1
....
```

But then I figured out that OpenSSL in the terminal does not use KeychainAccess, so I provide a CA root certificate.

And checking succeed :-\

```
openssl s_client -connect raceplace.localhost:443 -CAfile /path_to/rootCA.pem

.......
Verify return code: 0 (ok)
```

---

Chrome Version 88.0.4324.192
MacOS BigSur 11.2.1

Comment: What does details say for the certificate?

Comment: @AllanWind It's quite a long list =) What section does matter?

Comment: I don't know... but that's the data I would look at.  As you trust the root cert, I am guessing something is off with the cert you created.  openssl s_client is a good way to debug certificate issues

Comment: @AllanWind Thanks for the recommendation. I've checked it with 'openssl s_client' and update the question in a moment.

Comment: Did you import the root certificate https://blog.eldernode.com/install-root-certificate-in-chrome/?  https://www.pico.net/kb/how-do-you-get-chrome-to-accept-a-self-signed-certificate is another source.  Sorry, I don't use chrome so I don't know if the always trust means you already did that.

Comment: You can remove the first openssl session (not relevant) but the 2nd part is helpful just include the top output that lists the certificate chain.  This establish that it's indeed a chrome issue opposed to certificate.  You can use the -verify 1 (or maybe 2) option but it looks like it does something similar by default.

Comment: @AllanWind thanks a lot. Finally I've figured out that (at least in the end) is was just `NET::ERR_CERT_VALIDITY_TOO_LONG` complaint.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure what was the initial Chrome complaint, but when I visited my page the last time and expanded "Unsafe", "Proceed" and so on, I've noticed the error: `NET::ERR_CERT_VALIDITY_TOO_LONG`. That was because in my generation script I was so greedy and set a validity period for 999 days, and that was too much for Chrome.
I've set 365 days and now it's working.

I've put my scripts for Root CA generation and Self-signed SSL Certificates generation in my repo.
https://github.com/zablik/ssl_cert_generator

Hope it will help some other people.
Any notices are welcomed.

And thanx to @Allan Wind for helping me in comments ;)

Comment: I'd add a line for generating a p12 certificate, e.g. for java spring apps, too. `openssl pkcs12 -export -out device.p12 -inkey device.key -in device.crt -certfile "$ROOT_CA_PEM_PATH"; cp device.p12 "${DOMAIN_CERT_DIR}/${DOMAIN}.p12"`